Sending email from Visualforce apex controller
I'm having trouble trying to send out an email from a visualforce page controller. Not exposed through a site but rather in the UI.
Here's some sample code:
Contact contact = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = '003Pw000005Y121IAC' LIMIT 1];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setSubject('subject');
email.setPlainTextBody('body'); 
email.setTargetObjectId(contact.Id);
email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });

If I try this in a "normal" apex class or in the Execute Anonymous window, everything works as expected. But When I try this in an the controller I get

Messaging.SendEmailError[getMessage=Email address is invalid:
;getStatusCode=INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS;getTargetObjectId=003Pw00000AXApOIAX

I can't find any similar cases online ... what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Does contact 003Pw00000AXApOIAX  have an email? And it's not marked bounced?

@eyescream Not only does it have an email, I've tried different email addresses. All of them work using the code in the Execute Anonymous window but not in the controller

Weird. Send from constructor or a action/button? If from constructor you might have problems with "save as activity" because inserting a Task counts as DML, not allowed in vf page constructors (the mere act of navigating to page without clicking anything on it shouldn't have side effects). Can you post your VF code, as minimum reproducible example?

Well, you might be onto something there....
The thing is that, I tried to defer sending out the email to a @future method to avoid that...but it also didn't work and threw the same error.
Also: The fact that the error message is "Email address is invalid" makes no sense to me.
Anyway, if the DML is the culprit I would be grateful to get some tips on possible workarounds

Move it to helper action method (like you'd write a button click handler) and call it from <apex:page controller="my class" action="{!my method}"> and see what happens? 1 more idea: Is the SOQL written WITH USER_MODE/do you call stripinaccessible on it? Maybe you don't have read rights to the email field so it behaves funny?

Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try
